# How to find how many values in a column are not present

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, grep

I've been trying to figure out how to find how many values in a column which are not present i.e. has just a "."

For example

car.txt

```
Car           Colour      mpg          Year
vw_golf         blue       56          2006
vw_polo          red       66          2010
honda_civic    white       .           2007
ford_ka          red       .           2014
```

So the ones I'm interested in are the honda civic and ford ka as they don't have a number present for the mpg column and I want to find out how many values in the mpg column which doesn't have a value (in this case is 2).

The problem I'm having is the period seems to give errors when I use awk command.

Comment: `awk '$3 ~ /\./ {count++} END{print count}' file`

Comment: @jasonwryan that should probably be `$3 == "."` (else it will count decimal mpgs like `66.3` as well)

Comment: @steeldriver good point.

Comment: @jasonwryan so u mean awk '$3 =="." ' file?

Comment: Maurice, if any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Short **`grep`** approach:

```
grep -Ec '^\S+\s+\S+\s+\.\s+' file
2
```

---

- `-E` - allow extended regular expressions
- `-c` - print a count of matching lines
- `\S+` - match non-whitespace character(s), it is a synonym for `[^[:space:]]`
- `\s+` - match whitespace character(s), it is a synonym for `[[:space:]]`

Answer (score 0):

Another `grep` method, if your file is strictly formatted to have the mpg start at column 28:

```
$ grep '...........................\.' input
honda_civic    white       .           2007
ford_ka          red       .           2014

$ grep -c '...........................\.' input
2
```

That's 28 periods (for "any" character) followed by an escaped period ("a period").

Or with `awk`, [as](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405667/how-to-find-how-many-values-in-a-column-are-not-present#comment725638_405667) [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405667/how-to-find-how-many-values-in-a-column-are-not-present#comment725639_405667) in the comments:

```
$ awk '$3 == "."' input
honda_civic    white       .           2007
ford_ka          red       .           2014

$ awk '$3 == "."' input | wc -l
2
```